# How to show video file and word file in gridview from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

im the beginner of .net, im doing the project to save and retrive the files in asp.net with c# , i done saved the files to sql in binary format, 
and i dont know how to retrive the file in grid view,
also i dont know how to play the video file in gridview,
can any one help to make that please..

Comment: What do you want to display in grid? You want to play video in gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not a good practice to save large sized files** (like video,documents etc) **in database** (as binary or varbinary). **Instead you upload them to a structured folder** outside root and **save only the file name(name/path) in the database**.

If you really want to do as you asked do the following steps:

```
  1. Convert the binary file to a byte array as follows,

                byte[] byteArray=GetBinaryFromDB().TOArray();

  2. Then pass the byte array to the following function within System.IO namespace,

                File.WriteAllBytes (strng path, byte[] bytes) //This will save your file in the path you specified as first argument.
```

In order to play the video file you should design a suitable API (including a flash movie,light box/light window etc)..